# javascript prevent input focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to disable the focusing on an input triggered by an external library (the event is triggered by the library using the jquery trigger method).
Unfortunately up to now my code doesn't work, I'm just trying to stop the event during the capture. This is the code

```
function stopFocus(e){
    var e = e || window.event;
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    return false;
}

var inputParent = document.querySelector('div.bs-searchbox');
if (inputParent){
   inputParent.addEventListener('focus',stopFocus, true);}
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it easier to call `blur()`?

Comment: @Teemu He's not using the bubble phase, he's using capture.